# Searching an XSLT alternative to disable-output-escaping

Tags: xml, xslt

"disable-output-escaping" is not supported in Firefox, I'm looking for another XSLT way to process the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<text>
<title>Any title</title>
<para>First para</para>
<para>Second para</para>
<para>Third para</para>
</text>
```

in order to produce an HTML file have a <div> box (with a blue border) around the content of all the <para> tags.
The "bad" solution using "disable-output-escaping"  is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div></xsl:text>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <div style="border: 3px solid red;">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    </div>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div style="border: 3px solid blue></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
    <div style="border: 3px solid green;">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to wrap consecutive `para` tags in a `div`. Will these `para` tags always be preceded by a `title` tag?

Comment: Yes, the &lt;para> tags are always preceded by only one &lt;title> tag ; moreover it could exist other tags, e.g. &lt;image> tags, "mixed" with the &lt;para> tags that should be included similarly in the &lt;div> tag.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. Why can't you simply apply templates to the `title`, then open a `div` tag (in a "good" way), apply templates to all the other nodes, and close the `div` tag?

Comment: I don't see how to apply the templates to all the other types of nodes (&lt;para>, &lt;image>, and possibly also others) without "invoquing" also the rule for &lt;title>, as it is the case with &lt;xsl:apply-templates/> ; I want to keep the order of the &lt;para>, &lt;image>, so I can't apply first the &lt;para> rule and next the &lt;image>, etc.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the possible "other types of nodes" you need to process? If not, how will you prepare templates to handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't see how to apply the templates to all the other types of nodes

Quite simply:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>
```

That is, make your first template:

```
<xsl:template match="/text">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
            <div style="border: 3px solid blue;">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::title)]"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

then add the templates to handle `title`, `para`, `image` and any other node that may appear in the input.

---

Alternatively, if you have a list of all the nodes that can possibly appear in the input, apply templates to them explicitly:

```
<xsl:template match="/text">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
            <div style="border: 3px solid blue;">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="para | image | other | another"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is very simple.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
    <div>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

It gets more difficult if you have to process a sequence like

title para para title para para title para

For that the appropriate technique in XSLT 1.0 is "sibling recursion" - apply templates to the first child, and within the template for that child, apply templates to its first following sibling. Better, move to XSLT 2.0+ and use `xsl:for-each-group`. (In the browser, that requires a third-party processor such as Saxon-JS).

Comment: Sorry, my XML file was not sufficiently explicit about my case.

My sequence is better like

"title para para image para para para image para ..."

Where could I find more details about "sibling recursion" (with examples ;-) ?

Comment: Google for "XSLT sibling recursion". Or go to section 6 of http://gandhimukul.tripod.com/xslt/grouping.html. Or buy my book.